# Double clicking on c3js line chart

Tags: javascript, linechart, c3.js, double-click

I'm trying to create a double-click event on a c3js line chart. I've created double-click events with other kinds of charts with the following code:

```
    chart.internal.main.selectAll('.' + c3.chart.internal.fn.CLASS.eventRect).on('dblclick', function (d) {
    var $$ = chart.internal;
    $$.main.selectAll('.' + c3.chart.internal.fn.CLASS.bar).each(function (d) {
        if ($$.isWithinShape(this, d)) {

         ...

        }
    });
```

But when I try this on a line chart (changing `c3.chart.internal.fn.CLASS.bar` to `c3.chart.internal.fn.CLASS.line`) it catches all the lines in the chart, and gives no information on where on the X-axis I'm clicking. I looked through all the other values under `CLASS` but can't find anything that might correspond to the dots that separate the line segments.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I need to use `c3.chart.internal.fn.CLASS.circle`. That will tell me which datapoint is being clicked on.

I haven't tried this with circles turned off. It might not work then.